# C# UWP Copy database from installed location to local folder

Tags: c#, sqlite, uwp

I have a database on **"ms-appx:///Assets/mydbfile.db"** . I want to copy it to the local application folder when the application will start the first time. Database Contain a large number of data.

I try with this Code. but it gives me an exception.

```
StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(
new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/mydbfile.db"));

await file.CopyAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder, "mydbfile.db");
```

[image]

Here Is My Db File

[image]

Comment: Try reading the information into a byte[], and then outputting that byte[] as a file copy.

Comment: i am trying a lot but still getting the exception. but .txt file and image file this code worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried with a text file and your code worked fine.

Do you have the Build Action in the file properties set to `Content`?

[image: Build Action]

Where are you trying to run your code within your app?

Comment: for the text file and image file it worked. but if want to work with .db or .sqlite extension file it gives this flowing exception. can you try with .db file?

Comment: Worked exactly the same for me if I renamed the file with a .db extension.  I'm on an insider preview build, but I would be surprised if that made a difference.